# Rails: Analyze User changes on a page to insert to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I dont seem to be able to formulate concise question, but anyways:

I currently try to write an app which allows users to customizable save their statusses. However, I dont know how to pass the customized information to the controller action.

Dont I have to use link_to :controller => "controller, :action => "create", :params # => paramters

I can easily pass the status as a JSON object, but how do i pass the customizations?

a) i let the users choose the two persons among the many people that may like to be shown in the manner: Person A, Person B and 6 other people like this. so i would have to be able to update the like array

b) I want to enable the user to delete comments, hence I will have to pass the array of the remaining comments.

Anyone got suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I am not sure I understand the question, but let me give it a try.

Let's say you have database full of users. So, we have (notice, only minimal fields are defined):

User model:

```
# fields name:string
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
end
```

Status model:

```
# fields status:string
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_may :status_comments
end
```

StatusComment model:

```
# fields comment:string
class StatusComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end
```

Then you should have a textfield where you write change your status in view. This in reality creates new status which can be commented on (so you can distinguish it from some other status).

Now let's say you have `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in your controller.

Then in your view, you should do something like. I have not tested it, but it should work or at least give you a decent idea what to do.

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1> 
<%= form_for(@user.status.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :status, :value => @user.status.last.status %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<div>
  <%= @user.status.last %>
  <% @user.status.last.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <%= comment.comment %><%= link_to "Delete comment", comment, :method => delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
  </p>
</div>
```

This should enable you to:

1. save new status every time you submit
   your form
2. be able to delete comments on status

You should clarify a) since I have no idea what is it you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Hi. thank you so much for your help. i think i need to mention, that the status is not yet in the database, and i also plan to save the status as JSON instead of using models, because the status is gonna be immutable after entered into the database. the steps are like this: 1. user selects status from the wall 2. user customizes the the status 3. status get written to database. that means i dont need to edit the status, rather than get the momentary state of the customization. i just dont know how to track the customization. probably use hidden input tags and update them with js?

Comment: as for a, you know how facebook displays the last two users to like the status right? "Person n, Person n-1 and n-2 others like this" i want to enable the user to choose, who those two persons are via two dropdown lists.